How do i check if a created folder in the Assets is already exist?
i want to check if the folder My Folder already exist before creating it.
private void Start()
{
    AssetDatabase.CreateFolder("Assets", "My Folder");
}


You can use AssetDatabase.IsValidFolder for that.

If you want to check if the folder exist you may use AssetDatabase.IsValidFolder(<path here>). Returns true if the folder exists otherwise false.
Link here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.IsValidFolder.html

I simply use the default Directory.CreateDirectory method for such cases. This method will do nothing if the directory already exists and will create all the directories if necessary.
The only thing you need to know is that it works with the absolute path so that the result code will be like this:
string systemFolderPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, dataStorePath);
// ensure the folder exists
Directory.CreateDirectory(systemFolderPath);


The only thing you need to know is that it works with the absolute path ... afaik all System.FileIO also works with relative path and will always assume the current working directory to be the root in such cases - which in Unity afaik is the project root folder .. so one above Assets. Just for completeness as it depends on the use case
